# Flutter App is Blank when downloaded from Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, google-play, build.gradle

```
-- Main Issue:
```

When I upload my app to the Google Play Store (Internal Testing), Im able to install the app on my phone, but when I open it, its just a white screen. I see the same issue in Android Studio when I choose "app" as the Configuration and build to the emulator.

Alternatively, if I create an apk via Build>Flutter>build Apk. Everything works as expected. I can also choose "main.dart" as the configuration file and build it to the emulator with no issues. So I seem to be doing something wrong with my "app" setup or maybe my overall setup.

```
-- Android.Manifest files:
```

From what I can tell, the two different build processes use different AndroidManifest files as I set them up with a different android:label and noticed the App label will change depending on which method I built from.

```
-- App Manifest
```

One is in Project>app>src>main>Android.Manifest.xml
This one appears to be used when "app" is used as the Configuration and for when signing apks for the Play Store. I believe the source of my issue has something to do with the activity. I currently have:

android:name = "myapplication.app.name.LaunchAppActivity"

But I have seen errors during startup that say the "LaunchAppActivity" class could not be found. I dont see any error in my AndroidManifest though. Currently, that file lives in:
Project>app>src>main>java>{myapplication.app.name}.LaunchAppActivity

**NOTE:  I couldnt create a normal directory in the java folder so after clicking "new" I selected "package" and put in my applicationId. This is likely where things are going wrong but Im not sure of the proper way to setup this activity on the app side. When I initially uploaded to the Play Store, I was missing the Open button and couldnt open the app at all because this activity was missing. Once added, the open button appeared but it led me straight to where I am now.**

```
-- Android Manifest
```

The other is on the Android side, Project>android>app>src>main>.Android.Manifest.xml

Here I also have a similar setup:

android:name="myapplication.app.name.MainActivity"

But this actually does have red text in my IDE saying it cant resolve class MainActivity... Regardless, this setup still seems to work. The MainActivity file lives in
Project>android>app>src>main>java

```
-- Project Setup:
```

Flutter 3.3.10
Gradle 7.6

In case its relevant, here is some info on my build.gradle files and Project setup:
In my root project directory I have an android directory, an app directory and my first build.gradle file among other things such as pubspec and my library folder filled with all my custom written code.

Inside my android directory I have another build.gradle (Project>android>BG) there is also an app folder with another build.gradle file inside (Project>android>app>BG).

There is one more build.gradle file in my app folder (Project>app>BG). This is where I have my applicationId (myapplication.app.name) and version stuff set.

```
-- LaunchAppActivity.java:
```

```
package myapplication.app.name;

import android.app.Activity;

public class LaunchAppActivity extends Activity {
}
```

```
-- MainActivity.java:
```

```
package myapplication.app.name;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
}
```

```
-- app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml:
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapplication.app.name"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <!-- Next 2 are to keep tasks running in the background -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <!-- Add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission For exporting logs-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name="myapplication.app.name.LaunchAppActivity"
            android:label="My New Activity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

```
-- Project>android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml:
```

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="myapplication.app.name">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <!-- Next 2 are to keep tasks running in the background -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <!-- Add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission For exporting logs-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:label="App Name"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="myapplication.app.name.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

As a result of the follow error messages, I've tried to add multidexing but it didnt seem to change anything:

```
-- Error:
```

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{myapplication.app.name/myapplication.LaunchAppActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "myapplication.LaunchAppActivity" on path: DexPathList[......
```

```
-- Update in Project>app>build.grade:
```

```
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't have an answer for why Build>Generate Signed Bundle would not give me a workable bundle but I did find another way to generate them that eventually did work.

To set it up I went to Project>android>app>build.gradle and added this:

```
android {
....
    signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias '{alias}'
        keyPassword '{password}'
        storeFile file('{filename}.jks')
        storePassword '{password}'
    }
}
    buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
....
}
```

And I had to move my keystore.jks file from where it was and put it in Project>android>app for it to be recognized.

Once that was all setup I just ran this command in my terminal (in the root Project directory) and it generated a signed bundle that worked after being uploaded to the Play Store!!

```
flutter build appbundle -t lib/main.dart
```